# Hibernate not persisting foreign keys in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity `Property` which has city field. Something like this:

```
@Entity
class Property {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private City city;

    ...
}
```

So each property (e.g house or apartment) belongs to only one city.

Now here is a thing, if I try to log generated SQL by Hibernate, it is generating the foreign key in a right way:

> Hibernate:

```
 alter table property 
    add constraint FKdn1hnohufcwdr4a401xabcjn 
    foreign key (city_id_city) 
    references city (id_city)
```

However, if I check my Mysql database, there is no foreign key there, only index is generated:

```
show create table property;
```

leads to:

```
| property | CREATE TABLE `property` (
  `id_property` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `deal_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `publisher_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `city_id_city` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_property`),
  KEY `FKdn1hnohufcwdr4a401xabcjn` (`city_id_city`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

So the question is why there is no `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY () REFERENCES` definition in my database?

Answer (score 2):

The problem ended up to be the database engine after I switched to `InnoDB` engine it started working, as `MyISAM` does not implement foreign keys.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

The annotation @ManyToOne is used to map two tables that have a relationship instance by a foreign key, it could not automatically create a foreign key in your database

Comment: Then why it logs that it is creating the foreign key?

Comment: I don't know how can you see this log. When does it log or when you start your application at the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the list Property in the City Entity and add the relationship there as well